# How to find critical points more quickly

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find and classify all the critical points of $\frac{1}{3} x^3 - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{3} y^3 - \frac{5}{2} y^2 + 6y + 10$.

I get $x(x - 1)$ and $(y-3)(y-2)$ for the first partial derivatives. So I have $x = 0, 1, y = 2,3$. How do I find the y-coordinates for the x-values, and the x-coordinates for the y-values? I tried plugging the values into the original function, but I end up having to solve cubic equations which I didn't have time to do on the exam and the professor said I don't need to. What is the faster way without having to solve any cubics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the thing is you have 4 critical pts.
(0,2);(0,3);(1,2);(1,3).... so you didn't need to solve the cubic...
And the above is true because the directional derivatives in any direction of the above given points are Zero.

Comment: How do directional derivatives relate to minimum and maximum? I don't see the connection

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has the following structure: $$f(x, y)=\alpha(x)+\beta(y)+C, $$ for some smooth functions $\alpha, \beta$ of a single variable and a constant $C$, which is irrelevant since we are speaking of derivatives. You found that $\alpha'(x_j)=0$ at two (one-dimensional) points $x_1, x_2$ and that $\beta'(y_j)=0$ at two points $y_1, y_2$.

Taking into account that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y)=\alpha'(x)$ and that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)=\beta'(y)$, at which two-dimensional points do both partial derivatives of $f$ vanish?